# Projectivity of a module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, projective-module, artinian

I need a hint about this question, I know all the different ways of defining a projective module, but, I don’t know where to start:
R is an left Artinian ring, M is a left R-module. I need to prove M/J(R)M is a projective R/J(R) module. Could anyone please help me to prove it?

Answer (score 1):

Since R/J is semisimple artinian, all short exact sequences of left R/J-modules split, so in particular all left R/J-modules are projective.

Comment: +1 Pretty much what i would have written, except I think for completeness we might mention why $M/J(R)M$ is a $R/J(R)$ module...

Comment: I agree - but as the OP asked for a hint so I might have written too much

Comment: @ArtW since I don’t know anything about semisimple yet, Is there any other suggestion?

Comment: A ring R is semisimple if for every pair of $R$-modules $M\subset N$ there is a module $P$ satisfying $M\oplus P=N$. An important theorem says that the (left) semisimple rings are precisely the (left) artinian rings with trivial jacobson radical. In your case, $J(R/J)=0$.